# Scalar value as an array?

Tags: php

I am getting the following error:

> Cannot use a scalar value as an array

And it's referring to this block of code

```
$q = $database->rankingPage($g, $f, $t);
    while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($q)){
        $u[]=$row['username'];
        $p[]=$row['points'];
        $userid[]=$row['userid'];
    }
```

More specifically the line

```
$u[]=$row['username'];
```

I don't understand what the problem is? 
Could someone help me out please.

Comment: Have you tried var_dump() 'ing $row to check it is an associative array as expected? And is $u definitely an array?

Comment: It wasn't declared as an array! I copied the code from another script and it worked there even though it wasn't declared! Crazy! Thanks..

Comment: It seems that `$u` is not an array but a scalar value. Use [`var_dump`](http://php.net/var_dump), [`gettype`](http://php.net/gettype) or a similar function to see what `$u` actually is.

Comment: May I suggest using meaningful variable names instead of single-letter variables?  Write readable code and you'll be better off in the long run...

Comment: Ok I will improve my variable naming.

Answer (score 5):

Do

```
$u = array();

$u[]=$row['username'];
```

See what happens...